# Can you compile a C++ file from another program to produce assembler output?

Tags: c#, compilation, external-process

Is there a way to compile a C++ file from C#, assuming the compiler (G++ or VC++) is installed on the computer?

Comment: A compiler's a program just like anything else. Just call it as you would any other external program.

Comment: The C++ compiler is named `cl.exe`. Search for it on the disk, and on MSDN for its arguments.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you are referring to VC++?

Comment: Ah yes of course. The GCC C++ compiler is aptly named `g++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to take the same compiler call that you would make in the command line and recreate it using the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class. The MSDN page has examples of how to use `Process`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would just invoke the c++ compiler with the proper arguments.  However there are tools custom built to do just this Make and msbuild for example so I would doubt that a new tool would better serve you.

Comment: I want to write snippets of C++ and then view the assembler. I havent seen anything like this? Closest is the dissembly window in VS2010?